# Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK - Can not create symbolic link : Access is denied

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, admob

I am trying to embed ads on xamarin pcl project based on link 
[for iOS][1]http://motzcod.es/post/154696375922/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-ios 
 when I followed the instructions. and trying to build  the following error occurs

```
>Done building target "ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades" in project "App1.iOS.csproj".: (TargetId:61)
1>Target "ResolveReferences: (TargetId:62)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\App1\App1\App1.iOS\App1.iOS.csproj" (target "_UnpackLibraryResources" depends on it):
1>Done building target "ResolveReferences" in project "App1.iOS.csproj".: (TargetId:62)
1>Target "_CollectBundleResources" skipped. Previously built successfully.
1>Target "_XamarinBuildDownloadCore: (TargetId:63)" in file "C:\App1\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.2\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets" from project "C:\App1\App1\App1.iOS\App1.iOS.csproj" (target "_XamarinBuildDownload" depends on it):
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(XamarinBuildDownloadDir)'=='') was evaluated as ('C:\App1\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.2\build\..\..\.xbcache\'=='').
1>Using "XamarinDownloadArchives" task from assembly "C:\App1\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.2\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.dll".
1>Task "XamarinDownloadArchives" (TaskId:40)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      Archives=
1>          Gmbladssdk-7.15.0
1>                  Kind=Tgz
1>                  Url=https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/7d719f8d49d44418-Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK-7.15.0.tar.gz (TaskId:40)
1>  Task Parameter:DestinationBase=C:\App1\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.2\build\..\..\.xbcache\ (TaskId:40)
1>  Extracting C:\Users\cm\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\Gmbladssdk-7.15.0.tgz to C:\App1\packages\.xbcache\Gmbladssdk-7.15.0 (TaskId:40)
1>  Unpacking failure reason: 
1>  7-Zip [32] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
1>  
1>  Scanning the drive for archives:
1>  1 file, 17657943 bytes (17 MiB)
1>  
1>  Extracting archive: C:\\Users\\cm\\AppData\\Local\\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\\Gmbladssdk-7.15.0.tgz
1>  --
1>  Path = C:\\Users\\cm\\AppData\\Local\\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\\Gmbladssdk-7.15.0.tgz
1>  Type = gzip
1>  Headers Size = 107
1>  
1>  Everything is Ok
1>  
1>  Size:       38983680
1>  Compressed: 17657943
1>  
1>  7-Zip [32] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
1>  
1>  Scanning the drive for archives:
1>  1 file, 38983680 bytes (38 MiB)
1>  
1>  Extracting archive: C:\\App1\\packages\\.xbcache\\Gmbladssdk-7.15.0\\Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK-7.15.0.tar
1>  --
1>  Path = C:\\App1\\packages\\.xbcache\\Gmbladssdk-7.15.0\\Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK-7.15.0.tar
1>  Type = tar
1>  Physical Size = 38983680
1>  Headers Size = 46592
1>  Code Page = UTF-8
1>  
1>  ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : Access is denied. : C:\\App1\\packages\\.xbcache\\Gmbladssdk-7.15.0\Frameworks\GoogleMobileAds.framework\GoogleMobileAds
1>  ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : Access is denied. : C:\\App1\\packages\\.xbcache\\Gmbladssdk-7.15.0\Frameworks\GoogleMobileAds.framework\Headers
1>  ERROR: Can not create symbolic link : Access is denied. : C:\\App1\\packages\\.xbcache\\Gmbladssdk-7.15.0\Frameworks\GoogleMobileAds.framework\Versions\Current
1>  
1>  Sub items Errors: 3
1>  
1>  Archives with Errors: 1
1>  
1>  Sub items Errors: 3
1>   (TaskId:40)
1>C:\App1\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.2\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(25,3): error XBD002: Unpacking failed. Please download 'https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/7d719f8d49d44418-Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK-7.15.0.tar.gz' and extract it to the 'C:\App1\packages\.xbcache\Gmbladssdk-7.15.0' directory and create an empty file called 'C:\App1\packages\.xbcache\Gmbladssdk-7.15.0.unpacked'.
1>Done executing task "XamarinDownloadArchives" -- FAILED. (TaskId:40)
1>Done building target "_XamarinBuildDownloadCore" in project "App1.iOS.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:63)
1>
1>Project Performance Summary:
1>     4015 ms  C:\App1\App1\App1.iOS\App1.iOS.csproj      1 calls
```

I am guessing due to permissions. so I tried to unzip the .tar file and places the unzipped files at .xbcache folder as stated. that didn't work too. is there anyway that I overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it's because of the way you're trying to extract the files. It's frustrating that it was compressed twice. I did it on Win10 using WinZip and first I extracted the gz, then went inside the extracted folder, located the tar and extracted it directly into the final location.